# I want the image to be placed in to the middle of the background image, but as the navbar is fixed it wont let me move it down

Tags: html, css

I want the image to be placed in to the middle of the background image, but as the navbar is fixed it wont let me move it down. When i do move it down the nav bar follows. How could i move the image down? Becuase it looks now that the image is dependet of the navbar.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(/assets/image/startsida.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 4em auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #fff;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #000;
font-weight: 600;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.logo-type img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

  .logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 16px;
  }

  nav ul {
        max-height: 0px;
        background: #000;
  }

  nav.black ul {
        background: #000;
  }

  .showing {
        max-height: 34em;
  }

  nav ul li {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 24px;
        text-align: center;
  }

  .menu-icon {
        display: block;
  }

}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
       <img src="/TeknikSnabben/assets/image/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">START</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TJĂ„NSTER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OM OSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="logo-type">
    <img src="/assets/image/logo2.png">
  </div>
</header>
```

Here is an image of how it looks now. i want the logo TS to be moved down in the middle. 
[image: image of how it looks]